# How to move the 350mb recovery partition on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning

I have this structure on my disk. I want to increase my `c` drive but cannot due to the `Healthy (Recovery partition)` of 350 MB partition. The `c-ext` drive space will go into the `c` drive. I can format `d` drive if needed. How do I do this?

[image: disk partitions].

I'm on Windows 8.1 now. Will I have to do this again when I upgrade to Windows 10?

**Specs:**

- Windows 8.1 pro
- 64-bit
- 8 GB RAM
- ThinkPad X1 Carbon Touch

Answer (score 1):

Just use advanced partion management tools like [EaseUS Partition Master Free](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html) to move the partition as you wish!

[image]

Comment: You sure that wouldn't render the machine unbootable? I couldn't find any link where it says it can be moved.