# Fix the order of Windows partitions to free up 'lost space'

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, bootable-media

I am not sure how I managed to do this, but somehow I incorrectly ordered the partitions when installing Windows 10. This happened months ago so it is a little too late to reformat and start again.
Can someone offer a trusted and verified solution to move the recovery partition behind the OS (C:) so I can access the rest of the unallocated space?
[Current partition order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ0QT.png)

I have messed up too many partitions in my life and don't trust myself to figure it out by guessing and checking. I would like to access the free space but don't want to spend a whole day recovering the drive after making a mistake, so I am really asking for a solution that has worked for others in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move the 350mb recovery partition on Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/1016422/how-to-move-the-350mb-recovery-partition-on-windows-8-1)

Comment: **Always** make proper backups before using any tool to move a partition on a disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1354574/how-to-expand-the-windows-partition-when-the-recovery-one-is-in-the-way and https://superuser.com/questions/972227/i-want-to-expand-a-partition-on-my-boot-ssd-but-there-is-a-recovery-partition-a and https://superuser.com/questions/1106092/how-to-enlarge-windows-10-efi-partition

Comment: There are additional duplicates to this question those are duplicates I found in 5 minutes.